# R : get string between braces { }

Tags: r, regex, string

**UPDATED**
I need to get the characters between braces { }.

For example,

```
a <- "{a,b}->{v}"
```

Output :
`a,b` and `v`

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself already? Why not sharing your efforts?

Comment: Is this related to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559859/r-arules-extract-lhs-items-from-rules ? If so, I expect there is something better than trying to extract from text. `arules` probably has methods for doing exactly this.

Comment: Yep, I'm looking through the documentation. Can't find anything yet.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **stingr's** **`str_extract_all`**

In the following expression `(?<=\\{)` is used to find opening curly braces, `(?=\\})` is used to detect closed braces and  `.+?` is used to extract text in between. Hence, the final expression would become `(?<=\\{).+?(?=\\})`

This will return a `list()`

```
str_extract_all(a, "(?<=\\{).+?(?=\\})")[[1]]
```

Please follow another example performed by me:

```
> a <- "{a,b}->{v}{d}{c}{67}"
> str_extract_all(a, "(?<=\\{).+?(?=\\})")[[1]]
[1] "a,b" "v"   "d"   "c"   "67"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to match strings in between curly braces *excluding the curly braces*, you may use

```
a <- "{a,b}->{v}"
stringr::str_extract_all(a, "(?<=\\{)[^{}]+(?=\\})")           # With stringr library
# => [1] "a,b" "v"
regmatches(a, gregexpr("(?<=\\{)[^{}]+(?=\\})", a, perl=TRUE)) # Base R approach #1
# => [1] "a,b" "v"
regmatches(a, gregexpr("\\{\\K[^{}]+(?=\\})", a, perl=TRUE))   # Base R approach #2
# => [1] "a,b" "v"
```

See the [regex #1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/eLrqN9/2/). Details:

- `(?<=\{)` - a [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that requires a `{` immediately to the left of the current location
- `[^{}]+` -  1 or more (due to the [`+` quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)) chars other than `{` and `}` (the `[^...]` is a *negated bracket expression* in the TRE regex that is used by default in base R regex functions (or a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) in NFA regex, as is used in the ICU regexps in *stringr* package)
- `(?=\})` - a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that requires a `}` immediately to the left of the current location
- `\{\K` means that after matching and consuming `{`, the text matched is discarded from the match value, so the `{` does not land in the results.  See [*Keep The Text Matched So Far out of The Overall Regex Match*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) for more details.

To match strings inside non-nested curly braces *including the curly braces*, you may use

```
a <- "{a,b}->{v}"
stringr::str_extract_all(a, "\\{[^{}]*\\}")  # With stringr library
regmatches(a, gregexpr("\\{[^{}]*}", a))     # Base R approach
# => [1] "{a,b}" "{v}"
```

See the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/eLrqN9/1)

Here, `\{[^{}]*\}` matches all substrings starting with `{`, then 0+ chars other than `{` and `}` (with `[^{}]*`) and then ending with `}`.

See the [R demo online](https://rextester.com/ZFM58732).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I'm answering my own questions but

```
j <- "{a,b}->{v}"
unlist(strsplit(j, split="[{}]"))
```

Apparently for braces and brackets, we have to put it inside `[]`

Comment: If you don't need to know what was in each bracket set your solution is fine. If you want to keep the information you can use grep with placeholders.  Regex can be tricky but it's well worth the time.  You could also split on -> if that's always present and remove everything before and after the brackets

Comment: Regex has always been "when I need black-box" , I realize learning it well will be a life-saver. As for the question, I could further split each { } splits with a "," split to get the individual items. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

below is code

```
var a = "{a,b} xyz {v}";
a = a.split(" ");
a[0] //outupt {a,b}
a[2]  //output {v}
```

Comment: Sorry, my question was a bit unclear. I'll update it.

Comment: I see that you used space. The problem is there may not be space at some instance, I need to extract between braces.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution

```
library(stringr)

a <- "{a,b}->{v}"

betw_curly <- function(a) { 
  str_sub(a, 
     str_locate_all(a, '\\{')[[1]][,1]+1, 
     str_locate_all(a, '\\}')[[1]][,1]-1)
}

betw_curly(a)
```

[1] "a,b" "v"

Comment: may be not so elegant as solution from @Rishabh Ojha, but it works.
In fact, I was trying to build such regular expression, but faild :-(

Answer (score -1):

The function `tools::delimMatch()` is designed for just this purpose.

```
tx <- '\\caption{Groups are \\code{ctl} and \\code{trt}}.\label{fig:gps}'
tools::delimMatch(tx, delim = c("{", "}"))
## [1] 9
## attr(,"match.length")
## [1] 38
substring(tx,9,9+38-1)
## "{Groups are \\code{ctl} and \\code{trt}}"
```

Note that a second match (`{fig:gps}`) was not captured.