# regex - extract strings between curly braces without the curly braces

Tags: r, regex

I have the following character vector:

```
text_test <- c(
  "\\name{function_name}",
  "\\title{function_title}",
  "The function \\name{function_name} is used somewhere"
)
```

I would like to extract the words between curly braces, i.e `function_name` and `function_title`. I tried this:

```
stringr::str_extract(text_test, '\\{[^\\}]*\\}')
```

but this extracts the curly braces as well.

I have two questions:

- how can I modify this regex to exclude the curly braces?
- how can I do that in base R?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R : get string between braces { }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38560283/r-get-string-between-braces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a regex lookaround to match the `{` as lookaround followed by one or more characters that are not a `}`.

```
stringr::str_extract(text_test, '(?<=\\{)[^\\}]+')
#[1] "function_name"  "function_title" "function_name"
```

Regex matches one or more characters that are not a `}` (`[^\\}]+`) that follows a `{` (regex lookaround (`(?<=\\{)`)

---

In `base R`, we can use `regmatches/regexpr`

```
regmatches(text_test, regexpr("(?<=\\{)[^\\}]+", text_test, perl = TRUE))
#[1] "function_name"  "function_title" "function_name"
```

Comment: Hi, could you detail a bit the regex you used? It's quite hard to understand for a novice in regex (like me)