# Extract string between curly braces using str_extract_all

Tags: r, regex, newline, stringr, curly-braces

I have the following code:

`myFunction.R`

```r
myFunction({
  lorem <- "ipsum"
  ...
  print("dolor sit amet")
})

myFunction({
  consectetur <- "adipiscing elit"
  ...
  sed <- paste("do", "eiusmod")
})

...
```

In another R script, I would like to extract all `myFunction` calls. Right now the best that I came up with was:

```r
library(stringr)
library(readtext)

script <- readtext('myFunction.R')[['text']]
matches <- str_extract_all(script, 'myFunction(.|\\n)*\\}\\)')[[1]]
```

But unfortunately, `matches` contain the first `myFunction` call until the end of the file. How can I improve the RegEx to match only each `myFunction` call?

Comment: `str_extract_all(script, "(?ms)^myFunction\\(\\{.*?^\\}\\)$")`

Comment: You showed two `myFunction`.

Comment: There are many `myFunction` calls, @akrun

Comment: The first approach did work, @WiktorStribiżew. `readtext` is a function from the package *readtext*; it reads a file as a single string -- it's missing a `[['text']]` access but I'm going to fix this in the example right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38560283/r-get-string-between-braces

Comment: Another duplicate is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080592/regex-extract-strings-between-curly-braces-without-the-curly-braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
str_extract_all(script, "(?ms)^myFunction\\(\\{.*?^\\}\\)$")
```

*Details*:

- `(?ms)` - turn on multiline (`m`, makes `^` and `$` match start and end of lines respectively) and dotall (`s`, makes `.` also match line break chars that it does not match by default) modes
- `^` - start of a line
- `myFunction\\(\\{` - a literal `myFunction({` text
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `^` - start of a line
- `\}\)` - a literal `})` text
- `$` - end of a line.